# Lista quadriculada: somente com CSS

Tags: html, css

Possuo uma lista com 2 itens por linha e preciso que cada item seja de uma cor.
Porém, o item de baixo tem que ser diferente que o item de cima.

Segue a imagem do que necessito: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou conseguindo fazer esta alteração de cor nos itens, segue o que eu possuo desenvolvido:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A grosso modo, necessito que na terceira imagem, seja branco e não azul e a quarta azul e assim continuando a alteração.

Segue código CSS do que tenho desenvolvido:

```
.lista_servicos{
    margin-top: 100px;
    li{
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        .box{
            padding: 50px;
            box-shadow: 15px 25.981px 60px 0px rgba(23, 20, 15, 0.2);
            .imagem{
                margin-bottom: 50px;
            }
            .nome_servico{
                font-family: $fonte;
                font-size: 28px;
                font-weight: 600;
                margin-bottom: 35px;
                min-height: 40px;
                img{
                    margin-top: -3px;
                    margin-right: 15px;
                }
            }
            .descricao{
                padding: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 50px;
                min-height: 190px;
                *{
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }
        }
        &:nth-of-type(odd){
            .box{
                background: $primaria;
                .imagem{
                    img{
                        filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(10);
                    }
                }
                .nome_servico{
                    color: $branco;
                }
                .descricao{
                    *{
                        color: $branco;
                    }
                }
                .botao{
                    @extend .transparente;
                }
            }
        }
        &:nth-of-type(even){
            .box{
                background: $branco;
                .nome_servico{
                    color: $primaria;
                }
                .descricao{
                    *{
                        color: $primaria;
                    }
                }
                .botao{
                    @extend .transparente_azul_escuro;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Desenvolve em `JS`? Ou tem que ser somente em css?

Comment: Caso possível, necessito que seja em CSS :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que você está fazendo é selecionar os itens pares e ímpares (*odd* e *even*) com o código `nth-of-type()`. O que você deve fazer é proporcionar o "cálculo" para selecionar de 2 em 2 elementos.

Para isso, utilize a seguinte configuração de `nth`:

```
li:nth-child(4n+1), li:nth-child(4n) {
    background: $primaria;
}

li:nth-child(4n-1), li:nth-child(4n-2) {
    background: $branco;
}
```

Veja este exemplo funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/vbc6vj61/